# TypeScript on useContext

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-context, createcontext

I'm following a React tutorial on youtube where I'm trying to convert the Project from JavaScript to TypeScript, and I'm having a lot of trouble with the useContext, I would appreciate it if someone were to help me here.
If you're wondering which tutorial here it is [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jx5hdo50a2M&t=3065s&ab_channel=JavaScriptMastery)

```
    import React, {createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';
    
    const StateContext = createContext();
    
    export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
        const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState(true);
    
        return (
            <StateContext.Provider value={{activeMenu, setActiveMenu}}>
                {children}
            </StateContext.Provider>
        )
    }
    
    export const useStateContext = () => useContext(StateContext)
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: From the question, it is not clear where the problem is. So please edit your question to have the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 options I've seen in the wild.

### Option 1

This option is a bit annoying because the type of StateContext value can be `null | StateContextType`. But in the code you provided, it will only be `null` on creation and not null inside the provider. Regardless, everywhere you use `useContext` you'll have to have a guard against `null`.

```js
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

type StateContextType = {
  activeMenu: boolean;
  setActiveMenu: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
};

export const StateContext = createContext<null | StateContextType>(null);

type ContextProviderProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }: ContextProviderProps) => {
  const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState(true);
  const value = {
    activeMenu,
    setActiveMenu,
  };

  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</StateContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

### Option 2

With this option, you cast StateContext value type to StateContextType. It means that the value of StateContext is assumed to be StateContextType. The only downside is that the value of StateContext is `null` for a very small amount of time at creation, before a value is provided in StateContext.Provider.

However, it's relatively safe since you're immediately passing a value in the provider.

```js
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

type StateContextType = {
  activeMenu: boolean;
  setActiveMenu: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
};

export const StateContext = createContext<StateContextType>(
  null as unknown as StateContextType,
);

type ContextProviderProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }: ContextProviderProps) => {
  const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState(true);
  const value = {
    activeMenu,
    setActiveMenu,
  };

  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</StateContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

### Option 3

Credit to Steve Kinney's course on [Frontend Masters on React and TypeScript](https://frontendmasters.com/courses/react-typescript/) for this one.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function createContext<T>() {
  const context = React.createContext<T | undefined>(undefined);

  const useContext = () => {
    const value = React.useContext(context);
    if (value === undefined) {
      throw new Error(
        `useContext must be used inside a Provider with a value that's not undefined`,
      );
    }
    return value;
  };
  return [useContext, context.Provider] as const;
}

type StateContextType = {
  activeMenu: boolean;
  setActiveMenu: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
};

export const [useContext, Provider] = createContext<StateContextType>();

type ContextProviderProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }: ContextProviderProps) => {
  const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState(true);
  const value = {
    activeMenu,
    setActiveMenu,
  };

  return <Provider value={value}>{children}</Provider>;
};

const Component = () => {
  // usage inside component
  const context = useContext();
  return <div></div>;
};

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <Component />
    </ContextProvider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Option 2 was the one for me, thank you very much, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

> change this:

```
import React, {createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';


const StateContext = createContext();

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState(true);

    return (
        <StateContext.Provider value={{activeMenu, setActiveMenu}}>
            {children}
        </StateContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useStateContext = () => useContext(StateContext)
```

> to this:

```
import React, {createContext, useContext, 
useState } from 'react';

interface Props {
children : ReactNode
}

const StateContext = createContext();

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }:Props) => {
    const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState(true);

    return (
        <StateContext.Provider value={{activeMenu, setActiveMenu}}>
            {children}
        </StateContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useStateContext = () => useContext(StateContext)
```